# How to run an eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to run an Eclipse plugin using these command but they don't work!
the tool is developed on Github and i want to try it. 
the last command don't work he use variables like ECLIPSE_PATH but when i try i use cd and cd don't work with the last command !

[Commands[][1]](https://github.com/opus-research/organic)

Comment: Providing a screen shoot with half the information cut off is not helpful. [edit] your question and include the full information as **text**. How doesn't this work? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you do the following? 1. Build the plug-in, e. g. via [Eclipse PDE](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/), 2. Install the plug-in into Eclipse, 3. Run Eclipse with the installed plug-in from the command line as described. If so, at which step were there problems?

Comment: i installed the plug-in into eclipse but i have no idea how to write the last command why he write $ and why he use variables like EQUINOX  i simply used cd command . sorry if it's a foolish  question !

Comment: Instead of using variables, use the command line with the filled in variables (the name of the launcher JAR has to be adapted to the Eclipse version that is used).